# Defer Code in Widgets - Page Speed

Tags: widgets, api, performance, customization, optimization

### How to UP Page Speed With Widget Defer?

Is there a way to **defer** a widget in the footer?

I have an external API in a footer widget which is slowing down my [page](https://lbryhub.com). It is not needed until the page is loaded.

The caching plugin I use (W3 Total Cache) gives me the option to defer other scripts, but not scripts directly coded into the widget.

What is the best way to manually **defer** custom code API that is in the WordPress widget area of a footer?

### Like This

[image]

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
baseUrl = "https://widgets.cryptocompare.com/";
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var embedder = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];
var cccTheme = {"General":{"background":"#ffffff14","borderWidth":"0","borderColor":"none"},"Tabs":{"background":"#ffffff08","color":"#eee","activeBackground":"#ffffff14","activeColor":"#fff"},"Row":{"color":"#eee","borderColor":"#016ac1"},"Trend":{"colorDown":"#b7b6b6","colorUp":"#50dcb6","colorUnchanged":"#dddddd"},"Conversion":{"color":"#006ac1"}};
(function (){
var appName = encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname);
if(appName==""){appName="local";}
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.async = true;
var theUrl = baseUrl+'serve/v1/coin/multi?fsyms=BTC,LBC,ETH&tsyms=USD,BTC,GBP,CNY';
s.src = theUrl + ( theUrl.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? "&" : "?") + "app=" + appName;
embedder.parentNode.appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: I have embedded an image in my website from Microsoft one drive. The image is in webP format but the format is not in embed code. Similarly how this code can be [deferred](https://theworldlinker.blogspot.com/2020/05/chinese-baby-gender-prediction-calendar.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code shows an inline script, which adds a new script tag to the DOM, which probably slows down your website's loading time. This is not an inline script tag then. Try adding this line `s.defer = true;` after `s.async = true;` to add the `defer` attribute to your script tag. It should then look like this:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.async = true;
s.defer = true; //add this line
var theUrl = baseUrl+'serve/v1/coin/multi?fsyms=BTC,LBC,ETH&tsyms=USD,BTC,GBP,CNY';
s.src = theUrl + ( theUrl.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? "&" : "?") + "app=" + appName;
embedder.parentNode.appendChild(s);
```

This should result in adding a new script tag (named `s` in your code) to all the scripts the page will load and it should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="https://widgets.cryptocompare.com/serve/v1/coin/multi?fsyms=BTC,LBC,ETH&amp;tsyms=USD,BTC,GBP,CNY"></script>
```

Comment: I added this but it didn't seem to make a difference... https://i.imgur.com/JE3GyqJ.jpg

Comment: @InvariantChange This message means, that your script is only cached for 10 seconds into the browser, which is really short and requires a fresh download of the whole script after the 10 seconds. If you really want to "fix" this, you need to increase this time. But that has nothing to do with async or defer for a script tag ;).

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with WordPress. It's about browser behaviour in loading scripts. You are right in noting that [`defer`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) will not work with inline scripts. So, the easiest approach is to add an [event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) to the script which will hold up the execution until the page is loaded:

```
window.addEventListener ("load", function() {
  ... your script ...
  }
```

Comment: How to defer scripts in a WordPress Widget is nothing to do with WordPress???

Comment: Nope. Just like a problem with your iPhone while sitting in your car has nothing to do with BMW.

Comment: @cjbj is right what he says.

Comment: Both cjbj and @T.Todua are right. It's just a matter of choice. I personally favour moving the script to a file. I will upvote both solutions.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a defer widget codeX function or something, but I see your point!

Comment: I added this to the footer widget area, but nothing shows up.

Comment: Nothing as in "no script in the source code" or "script in the source but nothing loaded"?

Comment: Nothing loaded into the widget. It was just blank. I will give it another go when back in the office.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "nothing loaded into the widget". The snippet disappears when you save the widget in the backend? Or the code doesn't appear in the web html on the frontend? Did you wrap the whole thing in <script>-tags?

Answer (score 4):

@cjbj is right, I upvote him. However, you can try another approach if you want - move that script into a file (i.e. `wp-content/your_script.js`) and then insert it into widget with `defer`:

```
<script src="https://yoursite.com/wp-content/your_script.js" defer></script>
```

p.s. your specific script looks not professional though(probably not written by javascript specialists).  To force it to stay within your specific html area, do this:

- put the script inside div: `<div id="my_cripto"><script src.......></div>`
- in the `.js` file, do this modification:

  `var embedder = document.getElementById("my_cripto");`

Comment: I just did this, but it ends up looking like this... https://i.imgur.com/cZ2Fszc.jpg

Comment: It needs to stay within the footer widget area! Seems to jump out for some reason.

Comment: @InvariantChange I've added needed part for your case in the answer, check again